# Expected consecutive heads (with bias?)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gambling

When flipping a fair coin, getting three heads in a row is pretty likely, getting 10 is pretty unlikely, but getting 100 or even more seems (almost) impossible in real life. Is there a way to calculate the probability distribution that shows the likelihood of flipping some $n$ heads in a row?

I'm interested in calculating the average number of consecutive heads one might expect when starting a series of coin flips until a tails comes up. And subsequently, if this idea can be extended to a biased coin.

In the comments, Henry says that the probability of getting exactly $n$ consecutive heads with a fair coin is $P(n) = 1/2^{n+1}$, of which the discrete sum is equal to $1$ (thanks Jaap for the correction).

So is it correct then correct to say that the expected value of $P(n)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{n}{2^{n+1}}=2$?

Comment: What's the question? "I wondered if there was a way to calculate the average expected number of consecutive heads in all of coin flipping space" is too vague.

Comment: Are you possibly just asking for the expected number of $HH$ combinations in a string of $n$ tosses of a fair coin?  If so, the answer is just $\frac {n-1}4$ by Linearity.  (Note:  that assumes that $HHH$ counts as two $HH$ combinations, and so on.)

Comment: That's not what I was going for, I'll rephrase.

Comment: Please edit to ask a clear, self-contained, question.  Don't expect that we are all going to go watch some video.

Comment: There are many other questions here about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20St.%20Petersburg%20paradox%20).  At the start, the probability of at least $n$ consecutive heads is $1/2^n$ and of exactly $n$ consecutive heads is half that

Comment: I've reworked my question, I hope it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Why are you integrating when it is a discrete distribution? $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = 1$

Comment: Why does the header refer to a bias which doesn't appear in the body of the problem?  More importantly, I still don't understand the question.  How many times are you tossing the coin?  And, as others have mentioned, that integral doesn't make any obvious sense.

Comment: @lulu I've edited the question to include the bias. I cannot possibly tell you how many times I'm tossing the coin ahead of time, I'm just assuming that I'll keep tossing the coin as long as I'm getting consecutive heads. Once I flip a tails, I 'reset' the count.

Comment: So...you meant to say that the probability of getting $H$ is, say, $p$?  Not necessarily $\frac 12$.  In any case, you are just asking about the standard [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: So that would then correspond with the probability of getting exactly $n$ heads in a row, and $n = 2$ would then be the average consecutive number of heads one can expect (in the case of $p=0.5$)?

Comment: No.  As the standard Geometric Distribution shows, the expected number of trials to get the first $T$ is $2$ (for a fair coin), so the expected run of Heads is $2-1=1$.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Say that $X$ denotes the number of consecutive heads and we want to find $E(X)$. In the first toss there are two possibilities; we get tail i.e. zero consecutive heads or we get head and continue to play and possibly get more heads with expected value $E(X)$. Therefore we get the following equation for $p$ as the probability of getting head:

$$
E(X)=p\cdot\left(1+E(X)\right)+\left(1-p\right)\cdot 0
$$

For fair coin, $p=0.5$ and $E(X)=1$